# Copy file not working

Tags: android

Hi I am stuck with opening file with intent. I have an image file in my data directory and I want to open that file with default gallery. For this i copied file to SDCard using the following code

```
        File src = new File(sourceLocation);
        File dst = new File(destPath);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

After executing the above code I checked the Filemanager and the file is copied at the destination in SDCard. But if I click on that file it will show Couldn'd find item. But if I long press the file from filemanager and copy that file to any other location then the new file will be opened. What's wrong here please help me

Comment: What exactly your `destPath` variable is?

Comment: Have you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: My destPath variable is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/file.png"

Comment: I have that permission